# cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: plugins, php, iis, curl, windows

I've been researching for hours, but I don't seem to find a solution. I've tried every single solution I've found.

We're running Wordpress 5.4 with PHP v7.4 in a Windows 2019 server that's behind an intranet in a Fortune 500 company (ie. Microsoft.com). I mention the Fortune 500 bit because we're behind a firewall that I cannot alter. The WP installation is running under IIS 10.0 ([screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17BUU.png)).

So everything's working fine, but I get the following error when trying to activate a plugin that we bought. Here's a [screenshot of the browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvCE1.png):

```
object(WP_Error)#1107 (2) {
  ["errors"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["http_request_failed"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(78) "cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"
    }
  }
  ["error_data"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

I've tried every solution I've found:

1. I downloaded "cacert.pem" from here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
2. I modified the *correct* php.ini file by adding `curl.cainfo="C:\PHP\Extras\SSL\cacert.pem"`. We know it's the correct php.ini because we installed plugin *PHP Info (WP)*, plus another plugin that confirmed this.
3. When that didn't work, I then added `openssl.cafile="C:\PHP\Extras\SSL\cacert.pem"` to php.ini.
4. I also switched from `\` to `/`.
5. I also removed the quotes (`openssl.cafile=C:\PHP\Extras\SSL\cacert.pem`)

After every change, we're restarted the server, ran `iisreset` and restarted IIS from the IIS manager. Nothing has changed.

What else can we do?

Something worth mentioning is that we had to use `Configure HTTP Proxy Server` in `wp-config.php` so that WP could work properly. I don't know if it's relevant or not.

Comment: Are you sure your intranet isn't using custom certificates? Just because your browser accepts the certificate doesn't mean the host is internally

Comment: Can you add the plugin? This would help a lot.

Comment: So you're saying that if the intranet has custom certificates, it's possible that this may provoke the issue?

Comment: The plugin is wpDatatables

Comment: @John I am facing the same issue. Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @AasimHussainKhan I'm resurrecting an old one here and you have prob forgotten if/how you overcame the issue but can you tell me did either of you guys find a solution to this? I too am using wpDataTables and have run into the same issue. In some other troubleshooting guides I found instructions to check that curl.cainfo was set. but that isn't the problem. Can you help? :O